# Поступление информации — ОТ или С?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Информация поступает **от** пунктов наблюдения* или *информация поступает **с** пунктов наблюдения*?

Answer (score 1):

Информация поступает **из** пунктов наблюдения **от** сотрудников (роботов, автоматов) или **с/от** камер системы наблюдения. В нашем случае источник информации находится (*где, **в** каких помещениях?*) **в** пунктах наблюдения (парный предлог: **в** -> **из**).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее - ***"с пунктов наблюдения"***. 
Но тут надо контекст смотреть, прежде всего - сферу употребления.

Вне контекста вопрос решается так.
Если информация "откуда?", то ***с пунктов*** (ср: "информация с мест"). 
Если - "от кого?" - то информация ***от пунктов***.

В стилистически нейтральном тексте второе ("от кого" - "от пунктов") представить довольно трудно. Поэтому - ***информация с пунктов***.

"Из пунктов" мне кажется неуместным в любом случае, поскольку предполагает лишь место, локацию, но никак не участие в процессе.

Однако, в среде военных и, кажется, метеорологов ***информация от пунктов*** вполне возможно. Там "пункт наблюдения" зачастую рассматривается как активно действующий субъект (независимо от уровня его автоматизации), как наблюдатель. В обычном, "бытовом", тексте использовать можно разве что для стилизации.